# How to make a draggable div with clipping

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a browser game and my game map is built on squares with a background. The surrounding layout is simple with `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<main>` and `<aside>` whereas the size of `<main>` is dynamic depending on screen size. It contains the map, but this map most certainly will larger than the visible area. So the player should be able to move the visible area of the map within this clipped area. Just like in any top down RTS, TBS or even RPG. I think dragging the map is the easiest way but also arrow keys to move the map one square to the direction.

I know how to write code (Java, JavaScript, Typescript), but with CSS I am lacking some experience and have no idea how to achieve this or even what to search for in CSS terms, except that `clip-path` could be an option. Can anyone point me in the right direction or even provide some code snippet?

Comment: Not sure about clipping. But maybe this could help you?
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the CSS background properties such as `background-image`, `background-size` and `background-position` to add a map image to your element. Then work some JavaScript magic to change the `background-position` based on the position of the cursor and to make sure you don't drag the map out of view.

```js
var map = document.getElementById("map");
var backgroundSize = window.getComputedStyle(map).getPropertyValue("background-size").split(" ");
var mapWidth = map.offsetWidth;
var mapHeight = map.offsetHeight;

//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(map);

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();

        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;

        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        var backgroundPos = window.getComputedStyle(elmnt).getPropertyValue("background-position").split(" ");

        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;

        // set the element's new position:
        var x = backgroundPos[0].slice(0, -2) - pos1; 
        var y = backgroundPos[1].slice(0, -2) - pos2; 

        if ( x > ( mapWidth - backgroundSize[0].slice(0, -2) ) && y > ( mapHeight - backgroundSize[1].slice(0, -2) ) && x < 0 && y < 0 ) {
            elmnt.style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px ' + y + 'px';
        }
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

```css
#map {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #444;
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Europe_topography_map_en.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -250px -480px;
    background-size: 1500px 1200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

### Alternative solution

As requested a solution that will let you position a matrix of tiles using CSS grid.

```js
var border = document.getElementById("border");
var map = document.getElementById("map");
var borderWidth = window.getComputedStyle(border).getPropertyValue("width").slice(0, -2);
var borderHeight = window.getComputedStyle(border).getPropertyValue("height").slice(0, -2);
var mapWidth = map.offsetWidth;
var mapHeight = map.offsetHeight;

//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(border);

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();

        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;

        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();

        // var backgroundPos = window.getComputedStyle(elmnt).getPropertyValue("background-position").split(" ");
        var mapTop = window.getComputedStyle(map).getPropertyValue("top");
        var mapLeft = window.getComputedStyle(map).getPropertyValue("left");

        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;

        // set the element's new position:
        var x = mapLeft.slice(0, -2) - pos1; 
        var y = mapTop.slice(0, -2) - pos2; 

        if ( x > ( borderWidth - mapWidth ) && y > ( borderHeight - mapHeight ) && x < 0 && y < 0 ) {
            map.style.left = x + 'px';
            map.style.top = y + 'px';
        }
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

```css
#border {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border:3px solid #444;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#map {
    width: 600px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
}

.tile {
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('https://i1.wp.com/d.tile.stamen.com/terrain/10/174/400.jpg?resize=256%2C256');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
    <div id="map">
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example it gives me some ideas, seems I wasn't clear enough in the question. I don't have an image for the map, but actual tiles each with a background image. Combined these tiles placed in a matrix make up the map. So I can't work with background-position, but I'll give it a try with negative margins.

Comment: Added an alternative solution that will let you use a matrix of tiles.

Comment: thanks. Do you think absolute positioning with negative values or negative margins make any difference? The latter is what I'm currently implementing. The advantage for me is that currently set the position to relative for the map, so the units can be absolute positioned.

Comment: I don't think that will make much of a difference. If that works for your specific setup go for it. :)